# Specify dependencies for Maven classifiers

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, classification

I have a pom.xml file with two classifiers. Maven generates a "WAR" with all the files in the project and a "JAR" only with the folders I selected.

However, I don't know how to indicate that the dependencies contained in the POM only correspond to the case of the "WAR" file. The classes in the "JAR" doesn't have dependencies.

This is a problem for me because if I add the "JAR" as dependency of other project, Maven will look for all the dependencies, creating sometimes cycle dependencies.

This is my pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>name</name>
<description>description</description>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>a.dependency.groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>articfact1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>all</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1.redhat-4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pojos</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>pojos</classifier>
                        <includes>
                            <include>my/project/pojos/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this is how I add the dependency in other projects to include just the pojos JAR:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>pojos</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats actually not the 'maven' way of doing thing right.
you should have a pom.xml for the jar project that has those pojos.

than you should have another pom.xml for the war project that has the first project as a dependency.

you shouldn't create multiple different artifacts in 1 pom even if you can.
as you can see, it causes logical issues.

Comment: Thank you sagie. I used to have just one project and manually generate jars with subparts of it, but trying to keep this idea with maven it's causing me a lot of troubles. I'll change the way my projects are organized.